# How to open print dialog box when clicked on print report instead of saving/downloading it to our computer in Odoo 10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, report

I want to print a report which should not directly download/save to my computer instead it should open a print dialog box. Say suppose my report type is HTML. This is with Odoo Community ver10.

Answer (score 2):

First, create the record of the ir.values

```
<record model="ir.values" id="ir_values_sale_order">
           <field name="key2" eval="'client_print_multi'"/>
           <field name="model" eval="'sale.order'"/>
           <field name="name">Open Form</field>
           <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,%d'%action_report_wizard"/>
    </record>
```

It will create the menu item on the print option on the top.

In it i metioned

```
 <field name="model" eval="'sale.order'"/>
```

So, It will create a menu on the sale order list view.

Also you can see in about record

```
<field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,%d'%action_report_wizard"/>
```

We have our action of the form which we want to open on click.

You can specify your own action's external id here instead of `action_report_wizard`

And i hope that you have some fields and button on that form view to print the report.

eg.
**Action and Form view :**

```
<record id="action_report_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Report</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>        
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_report_wizard_form"/>
        <field name="target">new</field>        
    </record>
    <record id="view_report_wizard_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">view.report.wizard.form</field>
                <field name="model">sale.order</field>
                <field name="type">form</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form string="Report">
                        <group cols="4" colspan="2">
                         <!-- Some fields may be for filter -->
                        </group>
                        <footer>
                            <button  icon="gtk-cancel" special="cancel" string="Cancel"/>
                            <button  icon="gtk-apply" name="print_report" string="Print Report" type="object"/>
                        </footer>
                    </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

And on click of the Print Report it will call the method print_report where you can return the report as you say you have html report.

```
@api.multi
def print_report(self):
    # RETURN YOUR REPORT
```

I hope this will help you.